how to render a specific piece of data from Mysql database to my front end html using Js and node
so i am building a note system and how i have it setup is that on the home page it gives you a preview of the note and if you want to see the whole note you click on it and it pulls up a modal pop-up and would display the full note. im having trouble building my fetch request to get the specified note and then render it into the modal. any suggestions would very appreciated
iv tried just building a basic fetch request but i can only really find examples of POST requests or generic GETs that would just all my notes, not a specific one.
<div id="noteDisplay" class="noteDisplay">
<ul>
    <% note.forEach(note =>{ %>

    
    <li>
        <p><%= note.title%></p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p><%= note.body.substring(0, 250)  %> <span class="noteViewModalBtn" id=<%= note.NoteId %>>...</span></p>
    </li>
    <% }) %>
</ul>



    ×
<div class="noteViewModalContent">

    
</div> 

    document.querySelectorAll('.noteViewModalBtn').forEach(item => {
item.addEventListener('click', event => {
//handle click
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/note")
    .then()
noteViewModal.style.display = "flex";
})

})
app.get("/note", checkNotAuthenticated, async(req, res) =>{  

const note = await getNote(id)
res.send(note)

})
 async function getNote(id){
const [rows] = await pool.query(`
    SELECT *
    FROM userNotes
    Where NoteId = ?
    `, [id])
    return rows

}

You're using a value called id here:
const note = await getNote(id)

But that variable was never declared, nor was any "id" value sent to the server.  (Surely this is producing an error.  If you're not noticing an error then you're not looking in the right place.  This error should be visible in the server-side JavaScript console.)
You can add it as a route parameter, for example:
app.get("/note/:id", checkNotAuthenticated, async(req, res) => {

Notice the :id in the URL.  Any value provided would be in the params object on the req object.  For example:
const note = await getNote(req.params.id)

Then you just need to send a value when making the request from the client.  For example:
item.addEventListener('click', event => {
  fetch(`http://localhost:8080/note/${item.id}`)

This is assuming the id value on your element(s) is what you're looking for:
<span class="noteViewModalBtn" id=<%= note.NoteId %>>


Adding to this, if you (OP) did not already do this, I can strongly recommend making a dedicated database class (something like this) and either expand this class with methods like getNote() or have another class doing that.
